# Dynamically added hash properties to Rails Model instance object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There is a model

```
class PlaylistModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    /* code */
end
```

And then in a controller action there is code like this

```
PlaylistController < ActionController::Base
  def a_action
    @item = Playlist.find(10)
    @item[:visited] = true     
  end
end
```

However there is no `visited` attribute defined in `PlaylistModel` (or in the schema for the playlist table)!  It looks like a new attribute is being dynamically added to the object. Is this what is going on and where is all this functionality defined / where can I read more about it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Interesting, it seems that you can add the attribute by saying @item[:visited]=true, but when you type @item.inspect the [:visited]=true attribute isn't listed... but obviously is accessible by typing @item[:visited]

Comment: The attribute writer doesn't necessarily expose all attributes when you inspect the model.  It only exposes defined column names and attributes accessible via `attr_accessor`, `attr_reader` and the like.  See the link I posted below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the attribute setter shortcut as explained [here](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000411).  It is pretty much equivalent to:

```
@item.attributes[:visited] = true
```

Comment: So what I wrote isn't really how it was intended to be used. As in it was intended to be used to write to an attribute defined in the ActiveRecord/dB schema, but it still works. It just won't be saved to the database when you do a @project.save

Comment: Correct, if there is no database column backing the attribute, it persists only as long as the object is around in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for though is virtual attributes... which can be defined in the model http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes